# Same spec, multiple assertions, readable output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing some request specs for an API now. I see myself doing a lot of assertions about the same kind of request. This includes (but is not limited to)

- Responding with a particular HTTP status code
- Changing the state of one or more ActiveRecord objects.
- Responding with a particular JSON data structure
- Publishing a particular event to Rabbit

Currently, I am writing four `it` blocks - one for each assertion. Each of my `it` blocks now contain a `post` call, followed by an assertion. As a result, these four block contain duplicate method calls (I know I could wrap this in a before), but worse: it hits the app 4 times.

The easiest way to avoid all these duplicate calls to post and subsequent request processing would be to place the 4 assertions under the same `it` block. However, this sacrifices readability and produces inadequate output when running the spec suite.

Basically, I am looking for a way to write something like this:

```
context 'products#create' do

  context 'success' do

    post '/some/api/endpoint', some: 'data', headers: {access_key: 1234}

    it 'responds with 200 OK' do
      expect(response.status).to eq 200 
    end

    it 'changes the database state' do
      expect(some_model.reload.title).to eq 'new title'
    end

    it 'responds with a JSON representation of the resource' do
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to match hash_including(desc: 'ription', price: 1234)
    end

    # and so on...
  end
end
```

I have tried putting the post request in a `before(:all)` block, but this stops me from using `allow(SomeExternalService).to receive(:some_call).and_return('something')`

Ideas for doing this?

Comment: Have you investigated shared example groups?  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples